# Can google speech api convert aac audio files to text

Tags: encoding, google-api, google-cloud-platform, aac, google-speech-api

I am working with integrating Facebook messenger api with bot (dialogflow). Here I receive customer speech from facebook messenger in the format of aac.

Is it possible to use google speech api to convert audio file (which is in aac format) to text?

Answer (score -3):

AAC is a global type that contain MP3 or MP4 for example.
So try to use LINEAR16 as AudioFormat. If it doesn't work you have to transcode it before with AMR_WB for example

Comment: No. AAC is an actual audio codec (ISO 14496-3), just like MP3 (which is in fact MPEG-2, layer-3 audio, ISO 13181-2). MP4, on the other hand, is a container format (actually, it is a short name for ISO 14496-12).